# How to get an assembly's version in Team Build 2010 Workflow

Tags: visual-studio-2010, xaml, tfsbuild

Is there any way to get an assembly's version number like we previously used to do with Msbuild with Team Build 2010 Workflow? Here is a simple example of how we used to get an assemby's version with `%(Info.Version)`.

```
  <Target Name="CheckFileVersion" DependsOnTargets="AfterDrop">
   <ItemGroup>
      <MyAssemblies Include='$(DropLocation)\$(BuildNumber)\Release\MyApp.exe' />
    </ItemGroup>
    <GetAssemblyIdentity AssemblyFiles="@(MyAssemblies)">
      <Output TaskParameter="Assemblies" ItemName="Info"/>
    </GetAssemblyIdentity>
  </Target>
```

I've found some methods to create custom Activities with many lines of code, but I think there must be a simpler way to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GoRoS had the right idea, but it only works correctly the first time.

In order to avoid this problem you have to run this code, or similar code in a different AppDomain from the Build Agent, Powershell and an InvokeProcessActivity can solve our problem.

GetAssemblyVersionNumber.ps1:

```
$error.clear()

if ($args.length -ne 1)
{
   Write-Error "Usage: GetAssemblyVersionNumber.ps1 <Assembly>"
   exit 1
}

# Now load the assembly
$assembly = [System.Reflection.Assembly]::Loadfile($args[0])

# Get name, version and display the results
$name = $assembly.GetName()
Write-Host $name.version
```

And the following gets added to your build process template

```
InvokeProcessActivity
    Name: Call Powershell Version Script
    Filename: "powershell.exe"
    Arguments: "-NonInteractive -NoProfile -Command " _
               + "c:\Builds\GetAssemblyVersionNumber.ps1" _
               + " '" + BuildDirectory + "\Binaries\Foobar.dll'"
    Handle Standard Output (stdOutput)

        AssignActivity
            To: VersionInfo
            Value: stdOutput
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call out to MSBuild scripts from TFS Build Workflows using the MSBuild Workflow Activity and continue doing this the same way as always.  Or you could create a custom Workflow Activity to do a similar thing.  The best way will probably depend on what you intend to do with those version #'s.

You can read about how to get started creating a custom activity here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jimlamb/archive/2010/02/12/how-to-create-a-custom-workflow-activity-for-tfs-build-2010.aspx

Also there is the TFS Community Build Extensions which has a bunch of ready-made custom activities you can use.  One of those is called AssemblyInfo which sounds promising: http://tfsbuildextensions.codeplex.com/documentation

Comment: If you mean to use `UpgradeTemplate.xaml` and continue as always, I knew that but that's not the idea. I have checked almost every related links in google (those last two included), and I am trying to include that GetAssemblyVersion activity to my project from tfsbuildextensions... Anyway, I think there must be a simpler way.

Comment: You wouldn't use UpgradeTemplate, you would use the DefaultTemplate, you would simply customize the DefaultTemplate.xaml file to include the extra activities your build process requires (e.g. calling a custom TFS Activity, or using the MSBuild activity to call an existing MSBuild file).

Comment: So, is it possible to run the code I posted above with MSBuild activity just to get the version? If it is, could you show me how please?

Comment: Like I said it depends what you plan to do with it.  You can certainly call that MSBuild script, and it will happily get the version number into memory then terminate and throw it away because the MSbuild script doesn't actually do anything with it.  If you use MSBuild to retrieve it, then you'd have to use MSBuild to do whatever is it you plan to do with that information too.

Comment: but how? How can I run that MSBuild script code in my TFS 2010 Build? Could you be more precise on it please?

Comment: Check out this blog post for a walkthrough of customizing a TFS Build Workflow.  Instead of adding a WriteBuildMessage activity used in the blog post, simply add the MSBuild activity.  http://www.ewaldhofman.nl/post/2010/04/27/Customize-Team-Build-2010-e28093-Part-2-Add-arguments-and-variables.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found a quick easy way to perform the operation I wanted. Using a simple Assign activity I've written the following code:

```
To:     VersionInfo
Value:  System.Reflection.Assembly.UnsafeLoadFrom(BuildDetail.DropLocation + _ 
        "\MyApplication.exe").GetName().Version.ToString()
```

After that, I can use `VersionInfo` variable to whatever I want. I recognize I'd prefer to avoid using reflection, but that's the easy and short way I was finding which doesn't use third party libraries or custom activities.

Comment: After your build agent loads the binary the first time, the build agent will not be able to load a new version of the assembly.

Comment: @Stanley.Goldman: You're right, as far as the assembly has the same version it won't work. I finally worked it out using custom dynamic activities and getting the version from the `AssemblyInfo.cs` file. Reflection is always dangerous for this situations.